# how to retain value in dropdown after postback in MVC

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I've got a db driven drop-down list in ma application by which i select a value from it and display data's associated with the selected option. Wen i do so he page reloads and the data associated is displayed but the value of the dropdown is changed to the initial value and the selected value is not retained. I have given ma codes below, kindly help me out.

My Controller Actions:FilterCandidatesStatus() is where i make the dropdown work and index action is for the page dat has the ropdown and te same page which values are displayed

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int? page, int? filter)
    {
        ViewBag.statusName = db.CandidateStatuses.ToList();
        int pageSize = 12;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var candidates = new List<Candidate>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Filter = filter;
            candidates = db.Candidates.Where(m => m.CandidateStatusID == filter).OrderByDescending(m => m.CandidateID).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            candidates = db.Candidates.OrderByDescending(m => m.CandidateID).ToList();
        }


        return View(candidates.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FilterCandidateByStatus(int candidateStatusID)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { filter = candidateStatusID });
    }
```

View:

```
function fnFilterCandidtates()
 {
      window.location = "@Url.Action("FilterCandidateByStatus", "NewCandidate")?      candidateStatusID=" + $("#ddlStatus").val();
}
 <select class="h3c1" style=" height:31px; width:115px;" name="list" id="ddlStatus" onchange="fnFilterCandidtates(this)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Status</option>
    @{
        foreach (var lstItem in (IEnumerable<Recruitment_System.Entities.CandidateStatus>)@ViewBag.statusName)
        {
            <option value="@lstItem.CandidateStatusID">@lstItem.StatusName</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

I hav given only the codes associated with the working of my dropdown. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Storing in ViewBag you can store it in TempData like this:

```
TempData["Candidates"] = candidates;
```

and after reading it in View do like this so it remians in TempData otherwise it will be deleted from TempData after first read, do like this in View:

```
@{
IEnumerable<Recruitment_System.Entities.CandidateStatus> candidates = (IEnumerable<Recruitment_System.Entities.CandidateStatus>)TempData["Candidates"]

TempData.Keep("Candidates")

}
```

In your action also same way, you have to persist in using Keep in TempData

Comment: I am sorry i din see ur edited code. I have certain doubts, should'nt i use viewbag at all in ma Index conroller and in the view? Can u pls update the entire code wid changes ? pls. I am not clear with it.

Comment: you have to simply store candidates in TempData with  a key instead of view bag and in view read it from TempData and Keep it in Temp by calling TempData.Keep() and when page reloads again Dropdown will be populated from the TempData["Candidates"]

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case if your interested to do via strongly typed view

**Try this //** MY workaround example you can use in you scenario

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            LeadSortModel lsm = new LeadSortModel(); // model class 
            var SoucreList = //Pass you list to this 
            List<SelectListItem> lobj = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in SoucreList)
            {
                lobj.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Lead_Source_Name , Value = item.Lead_Source_Name }); //here i taken text,value same becoz i want on select of text the thing what i selected should be saved not the id we usually :)
            }
            lsm.lead_sources = lobj; //leadsources will be present in Models like (public List<SelectedListItem> leadsources ;) . Here you are loading data to model and passing the entire model to make it strongly typed 

            return View(lsm); // return the model to view on initial load @HttpGET

        }
```

Later on post also if incase you are loading DDL in your view when HTTPPOST , just pass the model with the above foreach loop ..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I see, you send selected dropdown value to `FilterCandidateByStatus` and from there to `Index`. And there you give that value to `ViewBag.Filter`. So, you can use that value in view:

```
@{
   int selectedValue = 0;
   if(ViewBag.Filter != null) { selectedValue = (int)ViewBag.Filter; }
}

function fnFilterCandidtates()
{
      window.location = "@Url.Action("FilterCandidateByStatus", "NewCandidate")?      candidateStatusID=" + $("#ddlStatus").val();
}
<select class="h3c1" style=" height:31px; width:115px;" name="list" id="ddlStatus" onchange="fnFilterCandidtates(this)">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Status</option>
    @{
        foreach (var lstItem in (IEnumerable<Recruitment_System.Entities.CandidateStatus>)@ViewBag.statusName)
        {
            if(CandidateStatusID == selectedValue)
            {
               <option value="@lstItem.CandidateStatusID" selected>@lstItem.StatusName</option>
            }
            else
            {
               <option value="@lstItem.CandidateStatusID">@lstItem.StatusName</option>
            }
        }
    }
</select>
```